# issue with FaceBook.Helper in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

on ASP.net 2013 express MVC4 Razor

I installed FaceBook.Helper from nuget.

Now when my app attempts to run I get the following error:

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SimpleMembershipProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
Source Error:


Line 216:    }
Line 217:    
Line 218:    private static SimpleMembershipProvider GetMembershipProvider() {
Line 219:        var provider = Membership.Provider as SimpleMembershipProvider;
Line 220:
```

I was wondering if anyone has come across this issue and can tell me.

I added the WebMatrix.Data  and WebMatrix.WebData to references and I marked them (copy local: true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you add WebMatrix.Data and WebMatrix.WebData to references  ,you must go to App_Code/Facebook.cshtml and write above :

```
@using WebMatrix.WebData;
@using WebMatrix.Data;
```